# The size of ImageView

Tags: imageview

Can anyone help me?
Why is the size of ImageViews different?
The code you may find below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:minHeight="10dip">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
                android:text="Click"
                android:maxHeight="10dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/folder" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
                android:text="Back"
                android:maxHeight="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
                android:text="Folder"
                android:maxHeight="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/camera_alt" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried you layout with  `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"` and all the views have the same height and width in the emulator,

if i however use 2 ic_menu_delete and the third for example @android:drawable/arrow_down_float they have different sizes, 
so this means it's your drawable that have different sizes(they don't reach the maxHeight="10dip")